# Ember.ViewState and event handler

Tags: ember.js

I tried to play with the Ember.StateManager and got the following issue. I have a view with an event handler like this :

```
App.TestView : Ember.View.extend({
   click: function(evt){
      console.log("hello");
   } 
})
```

When I append the view manually

```
Ember.$().ready(function(){
    var testView = App.TestView.create();
    testView.append();
)}
```

The click event works.

But When I use a state Manager :

```
App.statechart = Ember.StateManager.create({

    start: Ember.ViewState.create({

        view: App.TestView;

    )}
)}
```

The click event works no more. 
What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from syntax errors in your code example, it's working, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/c3EY3/

```js
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'testView',
    click: function(evt) {
        console.log("hello");
    }
});

App.statechart = Ember.StateManager.create({
    start: Ember.ViewState.create({
        view: App.TestView
    })
});​
```

Which version of Ember.js do you use? You specify a view class as `view` property on the `Ember.StateView`, which is supported since commit [bc4d813d](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/bc4d813d40586332c203312716c72cf6024ac50a) (**2011-01-17**, available since version **v0.9.4**). Previously you had to specify a concrete instance of a view.

Comment: I use ember 0.9.6. I translate my code from coffeescript into pure javascript and it's working :) May be I did something wrong.